# Formatting double for showing only 4 digits

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

Is there a way to format a double number that always have `n` digits sepecified by user?

For example if user want to see always 4 digits, take the following numbers as example:

```
Original             Formatted
-------             ---------
3.42421             3.424
265.6250            265.6
812.50              812.5
12.68798            12.68
0.68787             0.687
```

I made up this but it just allows for number of floating points! it is not what I wanted!

```
    public string ToEngV(double d, int percision = 0)
    {
        string zeros = string.Empty;

        if (percision <= 0)
        {
                zeros += "0";
        }
        else if (percision > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < percision; i++)
            {
                zeros += "0";
            }
        }

       return String.Format("{0:0." + zeros + "}", d) 
     }
```

Imagine I call the above method for a number like `812.50` and I set the precision to  (this is now used for all numbers I am going to format). Obviously the output will be `812.5`

But if I give the another number like `1.61826` I will get `1.6` and this ruins the formatting in the page I show these number to users. I need that to be `1.618`

Thus I want my method to always show `N` digit!

Comment: can you specify what is not working here ? Do you loose a precision ?

Comment: I tried to explain more now...yes I lose precesion as well

Comment: I'm sorry, how did 812.50 become 812.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your asking to round or truncate numbers, so I wrote this method:

```
public static string ToEngV(this double d, int digits, bool round)
{
    var lenght = Math.Truncate(d).ToString().Length;

    if (lenght > digits)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("...");
    }

    int decimals = digits - lenght;

    if (round)
    {
        return Math.Round(d, decimals).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        int pow = (int)Math.Pow(10, decimals);
        return (Math.Truncate(d * pow) / pow).ToString();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var numbers = new double[] { 3.42421, 265.6250, 812.50, 12.68798, 0.68787 };
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToEngV(4, false));
}
Console.WriteLine()
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number.ToEngV(4, true));
}
```

Output:

```
3.424
265.6
812.5
12.68
0.687

3.424
265.6
812.5
12.69
0.688
```

Note that if your number has more integer digits than `digits` you will get an `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 2):

```
number.ToString("#0.000").Substring(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you're searching for, anyway give it a try:

```
    string FmtDbl(double num, int digits)
    {
        digits++; // To include decimal separator
        string ret = num.ToString();
        if (ret.Length > digits) return ret.Substring(0, digits);
        else return ret + new String('0', digits - ret.Length);
    }
```

Note that if your number has more than *digits* integer digits, this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
d.ToString().PadRigth(4,'0').SubString(0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RunSnippet()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(myCustomFormatter(3.42421));
        Console.WriteLine(myCustomFormatter(265.6250));
        Console.WriteLine(myCustomFormatter(812.50));
        Console.WriteLine(myCustomFormatter(12.68798));
        Console.WriteLine(myCustomFormatter(0.68787));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static double myCustomFormatter(double value)
    {
        string sValue = value.ToString();
        string sFormattedValue = sValue.Substring(0,5);
        double dFormattedValue= Convert.ToDouble(sFormattedValue);
        return dFormattedValue;
    }
```